# GDB broken whilst debugging - no console output?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, codeblocks

I've just tried to debug my C++ program after upgrading to Ubuntu 11.10 and it appears the gdb version I'm running (7.3) is broken for debug output.

What happens:

I hit debug, Console window pops up, Message appears at the top:

```
warning: GDB: failed to set controlling terminal: Operation not permitted
```

I get no output from std::cout calls, even just a

```
std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
```

Anyone able to help? I tried to google the subject and came up with a lot of similar issues, but not ones related to this particular symptom, and how to fix it. I've made sure I have the latest version of GDB, etc.

Addendum: I am using Code::Blocks as my ide.

A rebuild of my project with full commandline output gives:

-------------- Clean: Debug in DungeonCrawlerCPP ---------------

```
Cleaned "DungeonCrawlerCPP - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in DungeonCrawlerCPP ---------------

g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/ActionableObject.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/ActionableObject.o
/home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/ActionableObject.cpp:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file [enabled by default]
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/AppSettings.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/AppSettings.o
/home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/AppSettings.cpp:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file [enabled by default]
/home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/AppSettings.cpp: In member function ‘void AppSettings::load(const char*)’:
/home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/AppSettings.cpp:98:23: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
/home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/AppSettings.cpp:114:29: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/Container.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/Container.o
/home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/Container.cpp:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file [enabled by default]
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/Entity.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/Entity.o
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/Item.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/Item.o
/home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/Item.cpp:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file [enabled by default]
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/Monster.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/Monster.o
/home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/Monster.cpp:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file [enabled by default]
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/Player.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/Player.o
/home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/Player.cpp: In member function ‘void Player::attackMonster(std::string)’:
/home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/Player.cpp:36:43: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/Room.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/Room.o
/home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/Room.cpp:1:9: warning: #pragma once in main file [enabled by default]
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/tinystr.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/tinystr.o
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/tinyxml.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/tinyxml.o
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/tinyxmlerror.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/tinyxmlerror.o
g++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g -fpermissive -std=gnu++0x    -Iinclude  -c /home/reedja/CPPProjects/DungeonCrawlerCPP/src/tinyxmlparser.cpp -o obj/Debug/src/tinyxmlparser.o
g++  -o bin/Debug/DungeonCrawlerCPP obj/Debug/main.o obj/Debug/src/ActionableObject.o obj/Debug/src/AppSettings.o obj/Debug/src/Container.o obj/Debug/src/Entity.o obj/Debug/src/Item.o obj/Debug/src/Monster.o obj/Debug/src/Player.o obj/Debug/src/Room.o obj/Debug/src/tinystr.o obj/Debug/src/tinyxml.o obj/Debug/src/tinyxmlerror.o obj/Debug/src/tinyxmlparser.o    
Output size is 674.11 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 6 seconds)
0 errors, 9 warnings
```

If that helps?...

Comment: Bump - really need some help with this as I cannot debug properly with no console output =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer - for some reason C::B doesn't set global -g as default, so I had no debugging symbols. I still get the weird error message, but at least I now get console output :)